# Probability Calibration : For 2D image data, how to use the calibration?

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, probability-calibration

I have a model which takes 2D input data and does multi class classification in keras. I would like to plot the probability calibration curve. However, using the scikit function, it returns an error saying that it cannot process 2D data. Please help.

My code is:

```
model= custom_model()
# define and fit calibration model
calibrated = CalibratedClassifierCV(model, method='sigmoid', cv=5)
calibrated.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "<ipython-input-41-bcfb033e1749>", line 1, in <module>
     yhat_calibrated = calibrated(x_train, x_test, y_train)

   File "<ipython-input-39-a3023fc5b92f>", line 100, in calibrated
     calibrated.fit(x_train, y_train)

   File
 "/home/eee/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/calibration.py",
 line 133, in fit
     force_all_finite=False)

   File
 "/home/eee/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py",
 line 756, in check_X_y
     estimator=estimator)

   File
 "/home/eee/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py",
 line 570, in check_array
     % (array.ndim, estimator_name))

 ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

If not scikit, are there any other libraries that can help?

Comment: have a look at what you feed in. The data has wrong dimensions.

Comment: scikit calibrated.fit has support for 1D feature vectors ( batch_size, feature_dims). My data is 2D(batch_size, dim1, dim2) as in input to CNNs

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? I am running into the same problem.